# React dev tools not installing as Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome

When I go top this page to add the react developer tools:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

It states they are already installed when they clearly aren't.

Can anyone please tell me how I can install this extension?